# Is there a list of features that change when a character gains a level?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-levels

Kind of a new DM here. My group has recently finished one of their first quests and I decided (and was advised) that it was a good time to level them up. As we are all new to the whole experience, and the guide is a bit incoherent in this matter (though I might have overlooked it), I wish to not miss anything important. So I would like to know if there is a list of all the direct/indirect stat increases, feats gained, proficiency bonuses or any other kind of "perk" that a character receives upon leveling up. I understand that it usually depends on the class of the said character and whatnot but I would appreciate a generalised list (/link/pgs on guide) that one could manage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to know about the general leveling up process is on page 15 of the Player's Handbook, under the heading "Beyond First Level". The rest is unique to each class: the perks gained are listed on the class's level chart, and the perks are detailed in the pages of the class description.

(As for feats: since they're optional, they're detailed in a separate section on page 165. Basically, when you could normally take an ability score improvement, you can choose to take a feat instead).